Can't install php7.1-redis on Ubuntu 24.04 (and some other extensions)
I am newbee here, sorry if the question is stupid
I'm trying to install php7.1-redis on Ubuntu 24.04, but I'm getting the following errors:
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-redis
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-redis'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-redis'

I'm using a repository ppa:ondrej/php
Is there any way I can install this extension differently? Or do I need to wait for the repository to be updated?
I wanted to use other repositories, but I am inexperienced in the UNIX world and did not find the right repositories... I can install latest versions, but I need 7.1

You will have to download the source and compile it yourself or use it via a docker container image that has it pre-installed. PHP 7.1 is end-of-life and it's unlikely you will find it in any repositories for Ubuntu 24.04 (unless anyone else knows of any that are trustworthy)

ppa:ondrej/php does not provide the php7.1-redis package for ubuntu:24.04.
You can install the redis extension with pecl.
However, you need to install the php7.1-xml, php7.1-zip as prerequisites for pecl.
Following are instructions to build a Docker image with redis support for php.
FROM ubuntu:24.04

RUN apt update && \
    apt -y install software-properties-common \
    && apt clean
RUN LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php \
    && apt -y install php7.1 php7.1-dev php7.1-xml php7.1-zip \
    && apt clean \
    # https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php
    && curl -O http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar \
    && php go-pear.phar

RUN pecl install redis-5.3.7


thank you so much!
one detail, you say "ppa:ondrej/php does not provide the php7.1-redis package." - but on 22.04.4 I can install php7.1-redis from ppa:ondrej/php...

That's interesting. I couldn't find it listed in the directory. Thanks for this information.
